# including js file and using function inside jquery ready scope

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have js file named defined_tools.js iside folder js .

i wrote simple function in it

```
function xxxx(){
    alert("rt");

    }
```

now in my index page i included the file by this line

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/defined_tools.js"></script>
```

and in the head scope i write this code to execute **xxxx()** function

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

$(document).ready(function(e) {

     xxxx();


}); 

</script>
```

i got error in chrome console

**Uncaught ReferenceError: xxxx is not defined**

MY FULL PAGE

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Main Site</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/defaults.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/devtool.css"/>
<!-- Jquery Library -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/defined_tools.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/core_osx.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

$(document).ready(function(e) {

     xxxx();


}); 

</script>


</head>
<body>

<!-- Tool Dev -->

<div id="tooldev" class="ToolSize">
    <div id="new_panel" class="ToolCommands"></div>
    <div id="new_text" class="ToolCommands"></div>
    <div id="new_image" class="ToolCommands"></div>

</div>

<div id="workspace" class="DefaultWorkspace">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That looks like it should work... problem must be somewhere else.

Comment: That *will* work.  I think the problem may lie in the `defined_tools.js` script.  Is the code in there in an enclosure, stopping it having global scope?  Is the function name spelt correctly (case sensitive)?

Comment: If you open the script tag with your define_tools.js file in the chrome console, can you see the function there?

Comment: Also, after the page has loaded open the console (usually F12) and try and run the function there.

Comment: This works when I tried it. Are you sure the default_tools file is named properly? And that it's in the right location? Do you get a 
GET 
file:~/js/default_tools.js  
error?

Comment: check the network tab in chrome and see if the file defined_tools.js is actually loaded otherwise there is no issue with your code

Comment: @elclanrs This is really strange .
~ Archer yes it spellt fine because i have autocomplete in dreamweaver.

~Jason Carty , yes when i click in the error line it moved me to the  js file and stand in the function .

Comment: I GOT IT the error where in other js file included in the same page .

Answer (score 0):

In defined_tools.js file, try to change function definition for this:

```
document.xxxx = function() {
  alert("RT");
}
```

And import the jQuery file after the defined_tools.js.